# .NET ListBox - Disable selecting items on mouse over

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, selection

I have a ListBox in single-selection-mode containing some items. I implemented that the user is able to reorder the items by drag&drop. Everything works fine but it looks really ugly because the listbox automatically selects an item if the mousebutton is down and the cursor is moving over a item.

To be specific:
To disable flickering in some situations I only move items when the item is dragged more than half over another item. When I start dragging item1 over item2 to place it behind item2, I want item1 to be selected while dragging. What happens is that item2 gets selected as soon as the cursor moves over item2. How can I get rid of this behavior?

I already tried to set e.Handled = true in PreviewMouseMove while dragging items, but this won't help.

If you like to see the code, it's here: http://pastebin.com/GTj96qV9. It is a behavior which enables any listbox which has a IList as DataSource to reorder its content by dragging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest solution for me was to inherit from ItemsControl and implement my own "Selector".

Answer (score 0):

This could screw over up the drop part, but did you try giving the ListBoxItem mouse capture? The MSDN has [more details about this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.capturemouse.aspx).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a ListView.   And I did not go into the detail of you code.   But I do PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown on the ListViewItem and I don't have the problem you describe.

```
 <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ListView1Item_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
                <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" />
                <EventSetter Event="DragDrop.Drop" Handler="ListView1Item_DragDrop" />
                <Style.Triggers>                     
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DispDetail}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```